# Adobe flash update prompt appears after starting Windows

Tags: flash

After every start or restart following windows appears , even if I already have updated flash player multiple times. But it asks for update repeatedly. I have disabled it from startup program list but still it appears in every restart.

[image: Adobe Update]

Comment: Use AutoRuns to actually disable the registry key that's controlling this behavior.

Comment: But why is it asking for update when it's already updated?

Comment: If I were to hazard to make a guess it actually isn't updated.

Comment: It could be a fake(malicious) "adobe flash updater". Check records in Task Scheduler, legal adobe's updater set there. Use [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) as @Ramhound suggested, but run it "as administrator" to spot everything that runs on start